# Como cambiar el color de option en css al darle click

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, estilos

Tengo una tabla con bootstrapduallistbox, y quiero que en la primera tabla los option sean rojos y en la otra cuando les de click y pasen a la otra se pongan en azul.

Adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto parte del codigo.

```
    $(function () {
        var demo2 = $('#ClienteId').bootstrapDualListbox({
            nonSelectedListLabel: 'Clientes Disponibles',
            selectedListLabel: 'Clientes Asignados',
            preserveSelectionOnMove: 'moved',
            moveOnSelect: false,
            infoText: 'Total {0}',
            infoTextEmpty: 'Vacio',
            filterPlaceHolder: 'Filtrar Clientes',
            moveSelectedLabel: 'Agregar Selección',
            moveAllLabel: 'Agregar Todos',
            removeSelectedLabel: 'Remover Selección',
            removeAllLabel: 'Remover Todos',
            filterTextClear: 'Mostrar Todos',
            infoTextFiltered: "<span class='label label-warning'>Filtrados</span> {0} de {1}"
            //nonSelectedFilter: 'ion ([7-9]|[1][0-2])'
        });
        $()
    });
```

Esto es lo que uso para el listbox de bootstrap, lo que me genera la tabla. y un archico css externo que uso para el background de los options.

Comment: Buenas noches. Deberías mostrarnos el código para poder ayudarte y cual es la parte que no te funciona. Inicialmente te diría que es facil hacerlo con JS con un evento "click" que cambie el background color de dicho el emento al clickearlo.

Comment: Ya te edite una parte de la publicacion

Comment: No se si te refieres a esto: #bootstrap-duallistbox-selected-list_ {  background-color: blue; }. Ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/o6nx79rd/